# Xamarin: System.InvalidOperationException when Initializing WSDL ServiceClient

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl, xamarin

I'm trying to make Xamarin app, which will be working with web service via WCF over WSDL.
I have .wsdl file and .cs file generated by SvcUtil using .wsdl file.

When I do next:

```
ServiceClient _mobileService;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential)
        {
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = long.MaxValue,
            MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
            MaxBufferPoolSize = long.MaxValue,
            ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5),
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5),
            OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5),
            CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5),
            ReaderQuotas =
            {
                MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue,
                MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue,
                MaxDepth = int.MaxValue,
                MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue,
                MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue
            },
            Security = {Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport}
        };

        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://ThereIsMySite/PathToService");

        _mobileService = new ServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
        _mobileService.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
```

I got exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation 'activateAsync' contains a message with    parameters. Strongly-typed or untyped message can be paired only with strongly-typed, untyped or void message.

 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.Validate (System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription od, Boolean isRpc, Boolean isEncoded) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription od, Boolean isRpc, Boolean isEncoded) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Then I tried same code in console project (.Net 4.5), and there is no error.

Is there know how to make it work on Xamarin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13074

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential is not supported in Mono yet, you may want to use 
BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport at the moment.

ref: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/44741/#Comment_44741